# Checkbox and hexadecimal equivalent

Tags: vb.net

I have four check boxes, check box 1 through checkbox4. Consider those four check boxes as binary 0000. If check box 1 is selected, the binary should change to 1000. The same way for the other check boxes, the corresponding bit should be set. Finally the output that I want is the hexa decimal equivalent of the four bits. That is 0 throgh F.0 should be returned if no checkboxes are selected. F, when all checkboxes are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's loads of ways.  For example, if it is just 4 bits, add them up individually:

```
    Dim intValue As Integer = 0
    If CheckBox0.Checked Then intValue += 1
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then intValue += 2
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then intValue += 4
    If CheckBox3.Checked Then intValue += 8
    Dim strHex As String = intValue.ToString("x")
```

If there could be more than 4, it would be better to replace the middle bit with a loop.
The .ToString("x") on the last line gives the number in hex representation.  I think that's all you needed?